# error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to char opp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Method");

Tags: java

I am adding this a code this give below error:

> // Printing in a dialog box import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

```
public class ExampleWorking {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String  firstNumber,
                secondNumber,
                opp;
        int number1,
            number2,
            results;
        boolean use;
        firstNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter First integer");
        secondNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Second integer");
        opp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Method");
        number1 = Integer.parseInt(firstNumber);
        number2 = Integer.parseInt(secondNumber);
        use = boolean.parseBoolean(opp);
        if (use="+") {
            results= number1 + number2;
        }
        else{
            if(use="-"){
                results=number1 - number2;
            }
            else{
                if (use="*"){
                    results=number1 * number2;
                } else {
                    if (use="/") {
                        results=number1/number2;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Hello World");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Results is " + results , "Results", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

**Error**

> ExampleWorking1.java:21: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to char
>
> opp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Method");
>
> 1 error

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your code is that you have multiple compilation errors, and although none of them corresponds to the error message you've added, fixing them will solve your problem.

- Your variable `use` is of type `boolean`, but you're trying to assign a `String` to it, which are incompatible types, and also is not needed in your case. You don't need a `boolean` variable for storing a sign.
- In all of your `if` statements, you're using operator `=` , which is used for assigning value to variable and not for comparison (for more information about assigning values, see  [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html)). If you want to compare values, you should use `==` for [primitive data types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), and `equals` method for `String` - you can see why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Once you fix incorrect type of `use` variable and use proper comparison for your data type instead of re-assigning variable value inside of `if` condition, your code will be working fine.